# How can i take footer to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I want the footer at the end of the page on all of these conditions. When the page is empty, When the page is completely filled with data and when the page has a more height than a single page height. Just like the google has.

I tried using all 5 the position tags of CSS, and they didn't worked.

```
.footer{width: 100%; bottom:0; left: 0px; right: 0px; position: fixed;}
```

I was expecting the position of footer to be at the end of the pages when there are a lots of results and when there are no results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: `body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }`